# SNR & BER in GNU Radio

Tags: signal-processing, gnuradio, ber

I have to determine the quality of a received signal in gnuradio and for this either I can measure it in terms of bit error or signal to noise (SNR)
Can you please tell me which is easier to perform and which of these two parameters' readings will be more accurate in gnuradio?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of already available blocks that provide link quality in Gnuradio:

- SNR estimation in gnuradio can be performed with MPSK_SNR_Estimator block
- BER computaion in gnuradio is provided with BER block.

This is a very open question depending on your specific application. They could be easy and accurate both.